# How to get Azure web app service to enable javascript file change

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've made a javascript file change on my Azure app service web app.  I can see the change via FTP download and via App Service Editor.  However, when I log into the application, the desired change in behavior of the code, which should be very obvious, has not changed.

If I F12 (in Chrome) and look at the Source, the change has not been made.

I did a "hard reload" of cache from within DevTools (F12).  Still no change.

Is there something else I need to do to implement this change in the application, i.e. stop and restart the application?

UPDATE:

Light bulb goes on:  the JS is running from mini-fied bundles, so changing one separate JS file won't make a difference.  Would be nice to know about whether the app WOULD have accepted a change without restart, however, not critical for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can append a version parameter to avoid client-side caching. Try adding a caching buster to the URL for requesting the JS file. For example. "/app.js/?v=v1". The value of the version can be changed every time you deploy new changes.